# custom validator pattern with special characters Angular 4

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have a formgroup using custom validators:

```
return this.register = this.fb.group({
        username: ['', Validators.required, /* this.validateUsername()*/],
        email: ['', Validators.email, /*  this.validateUsername()*/],
        password: ['',
            [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.maxLength(50),
                Validators.minLength(8),
                Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()]+$'),
            ]
        ]
    });
```

I am trying to achieve validator pattern, but it doesn't work, someone help please.

Comment: what isn't working ?

Comment: special character

Comment: provided code, its validator.pattern I need help with.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to add a `/` at start and the end of the regex string like this.

```
Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()]+$/)
```

Comment: because the slashes are not required my friend. also you forgot the string quotes.

Comment: Okay. But string quotes are not required at all. Maybe you can give a try instead

Comment: Slash won't be the problem @UlrichDohou

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
new RegExp('^(?=.{10,}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()])').test('sssBBBB99!')
```

Answer (score 0):

validators.pattern to allow all special characters

To find any Special Character:

```
[ -\/:-@\[-\`{-~]
```

To find minimum of 1 and maximum of any count:

```
(?=.*[ -\/:-@\[-\`{-~]{1,})
```